# Rounding milliseconds in T-SQL

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008, datetime, rounding

In `SQL Server 2008`, I have the below column of type `DateTime` in a table.

```
+-------------------------+
| LTime                   |
+-------------------------+
| 2009-12-07 10:40:21.893 |
| 2009-12-07 10:42:18.173 |
+-------------------------+
```

From the above column, I want to select the `datetime` and round off the `milliseconds`, in order to get the below output

```
+---------------------+
| LTime               |
+---------------------+
| 2009-12-07 10:40:22 |
| 2009-12-07 10:42:18 |
+---------------------+
```

Greatly appreciate your help in advance.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Does

```
SELECT CAST('2009-12-07 10:40:21.893' AS DATETIME2(0)), 
       CAST('2009-12-07 10:42:18.173' AS DATETIME2(0))
```

Do what you need?